# Lotus Notes email voting button to work in the client and with iNotes

Tags: lotus-notes

We have a voting button in an email which works in the Client, is it possible to include a button in the email that would work for iNotes users?
The button is used to confirm that the email has been read and certain conditions understood.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Basically, what you want is for the user to click on a link that will run an agent on the server which executes the commands you have in the button in the Notes client directly on the server.